# Working with large dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a large set of data (approximately forty thousand value pairs), that ideally fits into [Int:Double] dictionary, but Xcode tries to reindex the file all the time and it just doesn't work.. the environment hangs, crashes..

What is the current best practice to deal with such issue in Swift for iOS?

```
class R {
    let array:[Int:Double] = [
        99502:0.1730,
// 40 thousand lines are here
        99503:0.1730
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is the first value necessary?  If it's a monotonically incrementing value, it seems like an array would be better.

Comment: Put the data in a file. Do not hardcore 40k values in code.

Comment: Yes, the first value is necessary, otherwise it wouldn't be a dictionary.

Comment: "put the data in a file" - could you elaborate? What's the best practice? plist?

Comment: For that much data I would use a database.